# Navigating back to a fragment using stack

Tags: android

So I have 4 bottom navigation section and I am using fragments , however I have a problem Once I insert my data the data is not populated, how can I go back to my right fragment say once I have added all needed transaction navigate back to TransactionFragment on the storeExpense.

Here is my code:

```
private void storeExpense(ExpenseData expenseData) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ExpensesContract.ExpenseEntry.COLUMN_EXPENSE_NAME, expenseData.getExpenseName());
    values.put(ExpensesContract.ExpenseEntry.COLUMN_EXPENSE_TYPE, expenseData.getExpenseType());
    values.put(ExpensesContract.ExpenseEntry.COLUMN_EXPENSE_CURRENCY,expenseData.getCurrency());
           values.put(ExpensesContract.ExpenseEntry.COLUMN_EXPENSE_CREATED_DATE, expenseData.getExpenseDate());
    values.put(ExpensesContract.ExpenseEntry.COLUMN_EXPENSE_USER_ID, new ConstantSess(getActivity().getBaseContext()).getuserId());
    Uri uri = getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(ExpensesContract.ExpenseEntry.CONTENT_URI, values);

    if (uri == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), R.string.editor_save_expense_failed,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), R.string.editor_save_expense_successful,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        checkBudgets(expenseData.getExpenseName());
    }

    getActivity().finish();

I want to add something like this      Intent intent = new Intent(this.getActivity(), TransactionsFragment.class);             startActivity(intent);    }
```

After the `getActitivy().finish()` I want to go back to my TransactionFragment how can I do this safely?

This code is crashing my app

```
 Fragment someFragment = new TransactionsFragment();
 FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 transaction.replace(R.id.container, someFragment, "Transaction");
 transaction.addToBackStack("Transaction");
 transaction.commit();
```

Error :

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
```

Comment: You should use `getSupportFragmentManager`?

Comment: next time please add the whole `Exception`, because this could be just anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works about like this:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.container, new TransactionsFragment()).commit();
```

to go back:

```
if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() != 0) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
```